# is there a browser object/class for g++?

Tags: c++, linux, browser

I am looking for a browser class that can be created in a terminal program in g++ that will create a page in memory and execute client JavaScript.

environment is Linux, server is h ubuntu 10.04 there is  no GUI installed, program would be an occasional cron script.

is there such an animal?

edit: removed vbscript

Comment: You can harness Firefox to do this, but you won't get vbscript support and I think it's a bit more complicated than just instantiating a class ...

Comment: Not in the standard. But the windows manager of your OS may have such an object. More details about your environment. (Gnome/KDE etc..)

Comment: [QWebView](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qwebview.html) from Qt comes to mind - it's not *meant* for non-gui uses but it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I particularly like [Google V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) for this.